Simulating Multilevel Data to Achieve a Specific Marginal R-squared Value
I am working on simulating multilevel data with the goal of achieving a particular marginal R-squared value through simulation. Given that variance decomposition in multilevel modeling can become rather complex when adjusting parameters at different levels, I've been attempting to approximate the marginal R-squared value through simulation.
Below is the R code snippet for a basic data generation process for a two-level model with two level-1 predictors (X1ij, X2ij) and two level-2 predictors (Z1j, Z2j):
# Load necessary libraries
library(lme4) # for fitting mixed models

# # Set seed for reproducibility
# set.seed(12654)

# Simulation parameters
n_groups <- 30   # Number of level-2 groups
n_per_group <- 30 # Number of level-1 units per group
n <- n_groups * n_per_group # Total number of observations

# Fixed effects
gamma_00 <- 0   # Intercept
gamma_10 <- 1   # Initial slope for level-1 predictor (X1ij - to be adjusted)
gamma_01 <- 1   # Initial slope for level-2 predictor (Z1j - to be adjusted)
gamma_20 <- 0   # Slope for additional level-1 predictor (X2ij)
gamma_02 <- 0   # Effect of additional level-2 predictor (Z2j)

# Variance components
sigma2_e <- 1    # Residual variance (epsilon)
sigma2_U0j <- 0.5  # Random intercept variance

# Data Generating Process Function
dgp_function <- function(n_groups, n_per_group, sigma2_e, sigma2_U0j,
                         gamma_00, gamma_10, gamma_01, gamma_20, gamma_02) {
  
  # Simulate level-2 predictors (Z1j and Z2j)
  Z1j <- rnorm(n_groups, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  Z2j <- rnorm(n_groups, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  
  
  # Initialize data storage
  data <- data.frame()
  
  # Generate data for each group
  for (j in 1:n_groups) {
    # Random intercept for group j
    b_j <- rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(sigma2_U0j))
    
    # Level-1 predictors (X1ij and X2ij)
    X1ij <- rnorm(n_per_group, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    X2ij <- rnorm(n_per_group, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    
    # Level-1 residuals
    epsilon <- rnorm(n_per_group, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(sigma2_e))
    
    # Generate outcome variable Y
    Y <- (gamma_00 + b_j) + gamma_10 * X1ij + gamma_01 * Z1j[j] + gamma_20 * X2ij + gamma_02 * Z2j[j] + epsilon
    
    # Create a data frame for this group
    group_data <- data.frame(
      group = j,
      X1ij = X1ij,
      X2ij = X2ij,
      Z1j = Z1j[j],
      Z2j = Z2j[j],
      Y = Y
    )
    
    # Combine with main data frame
    data <- rbind(data, group_data)
  }
  
  return(data)
}

My objective is to iteratively adjust the model parameters gamma_10 and gamma_01 to approximate the desired marginal R-squared value by updating them with a scaling factor. However, the method I am using has been producing some odd results, and I am unsure if there is a more reliable approach.
Here's the part of my code where I adjust gamma_10 and gamma_01 in an attempt to reach the desired R-squared:
Unfortunately, I do not have any experience with this kind of simulations, so any thoughts or literature references are appreciated.
# Desired Marginal R-squared
desired_marginal_R2 <- 0.25


# Placeholder for achieved R2 and iteration tolerance and counter
achieved_R2 <- 0
tolerance <- 0.01
iteration <- 1
max_iterations <- 100

# Iterate to adjust gamma_10 and gamma_01 to achieve desired marginal R2
while (abs(achieved_R2 - desired_marginal_R2) > tolerance && iteration <= max_iterations) {
  # Generate data
  data <- dgp_function(n_groups, n_per_group, sigma2_e, sigma2_U0j,
                       gamma_00, gamma_10, gamma_01, gamma_20, gamma_02) 
  
  # Fit mixed model
  model <- lmer(Y ~ X1ij + Z1j +   (1 | group), data = data)
  
  # Calculate marginal R2 using the performance package
  achieved_R2 <- performance::r2(model, details = TRUE)$R2_marginal

  # Adjust gamma_10 and gamma_01 based on achieved R2 (heuristic)
  scaling_factor <- sqrt(desired_marginal_R2 / achieved_R2)
  gamma_10 <- gamma_10 * scaling_factor
  gamma_01 <- gamma_01 * scaling_factor
 
  # Increment iteration counter
  iteration <- iteration + 1
}

# Output results
cat("Achieved Marginal R2:", achieved_R2, "\n")
cat("Desired Marginal R2:", desired_marginal_R2, "\n")
cat("Iterations:", iteration - 1, "\n")
cat("Adjusted gamma_10:", gamma_10, "\n")
cat("Adjusted gamma_01:", gamma_01, "\n")


